# Transaction going to pending state

Tags: pending-transactions, quorum

I have a private protected Quorum Blockchain network

```
instance: Geth/v1.8.18-stable(quorum-v2.4.0)/linux-amd64/go1.11.2
coinbase: 0x365...63c7ced
at block: 175 (Fri, 06 Jan 2023 12:47:38 IST)
datadir: /home/.../Nodes/Node2
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 raft:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

and the below is my genisis file

```
{
   "alloc": {
      "1ab...3a756": {
         "balance": "30000"
       }
   },
   "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "config": {
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0,
      "chainId": 10,
      "eip150Block": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "isQuorum": true,
      "maxCodeSizeConfig": [
         {
          "block": 0,
          "size": 128
         }
      ],
      "txnSizeLimit": 128
    },
    "difficulty": "0x0",
    "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
    "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

After a point of time, Node1 out of the three nodes created in the Network stopped working. I tried to manually restart the node and the node successfully restarted but since then, all the transactions in the network are going to pending transactions

The below is the result of raft.cluster

```
[{
   hostname: "X.X.X.X",
   nodeId: "5007d5...76b8c00c5",
   p2pPort: 24000,
   raftId: 1,
   raftPort: 51000,
   role: "verifier"
 }, {
   hostname: "X.X.X.X",
   nodeId: "10df749...17609",
   p2pPort: 24002,
   raftId: 3,
   raftPort: 51002,
   role: "minter"
 }, {
   hostname: "X.X.X.X",
   nodeId: "372e419...399a9a",
   p2pPort: 24001,
   raftId: 2,
   raftPort: 51001,
   role: "verifier"
 }]
```

I do not understand where the problem is. Can anyone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: please someone help me solve the issue. I created another test network with same genesis file structure and created 3 nodes in it.  After 151 Blocks in the network all transactions are pushing to pending state

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your config, you are on Raft consensus, which means you probably have a minter (leader) node that's producing blocks and learner (follower) nodes that basically blindly take the blocks from the minter node. The minter node is the one that picks up transactions and commits them to the blocks it produces.

You mentioned that you had to reboot a node. You might have rebooted the leader node which might have screwed up your setup.

I suggest you check the current status of your nodes and node roles in your setup. [eg with these methods](https://docs.chainstack.com/operations/quorum/configuring-consensus#raft).

Comment: Please check the content above. I have edited the post and added the result of raft.cluster also. I don't see any issue in that also.

Comment: even if i do any transaction on the node whose role is minter also transaction go to pending state

Comment: now when i try to attach Node1 i get the following issue 

`Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix Nodes/Node1/geth.ipc: connect: connection refused`